# Drupal 7 - rewrite all urls for a specifik page

Tags: drupal, drupal-path-aliases

I have a page (shop) in my drupal 7 site. On this page is a php script requesting a webservice.
The response depends on the URL, eg. /shop/pid-1234/pink-shoes.html will show a product with id 1234.
I therefore need Drupal to load the /shop page no matter what the URL after shop/ looks like. How do I
achive this? I have tried using wildcards in the URL alias module ($,%) but that didn't work. I have also
looked at pathauto and redirect, but didn't seem like they could help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an Apache mod_rewrite rule.  You can add something to your .htaccess file if you're using one.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not sure what to put in there. Drupal rewrites all urls as a default.

This is in the default .htaccess:

RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]